# Pyramid is not appearing on the canvas WEB GL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

I am trying to create two objects an octagon and a pyramid on the canvas. The octagon is appearing without any problem but the pyramid is not. I am attaching the code of the pyramid.

```
pyramidPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidPositionBuffer);

let pyramidVerts = [
       0.0,  0.5,  0.0, //0
      -0.5,  0.0, -0.5, //1
       0.5,  0.0, -0.5, //2
       0.5,  0.0,  0.5, //3
      -0.5,  0.0,  0.5 //4
      ];

pyramidPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
pyramidPositionBuffer.numItems = 5;
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(pyramidVerts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

pyramidColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidColorBuffer);

let pyramidColors = [
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0
        ];

pyramidColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
pyramidColorBuffer.numItems = 5;
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(pyramidColorBuffer),gl.STATIC_DRAWS);

pyramidIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidIndexBuffer);

let pyramidIndeces = [
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 2, 3,
        0, 3, 4,
        0, 4, 1
];

pyramidIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
pyramidIndexBuffer.numItems = 12;
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(pyramidIndeces), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

}

function drawScene() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-1.5, 0.0, -6.5]); // We store a translation to our matrix, so when the first object is drawn it will be in that position.

    // Connect the attributes with the shaders and draw...
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,octagonPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, octagonPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, octagonColorBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, octagonColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, octagonIndexBuffer);

        setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, octagonIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [2.8, 0.0, 0.0]);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,pyramidPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, pyramidPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidColorBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, pyramidColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidIndexBuffer);

        setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, pyramidIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

I created the pyramid with the same way I created the octagon but for some reason it is not appearing. If I try to draw the octagon two times it has no problem.

Comment: If you take some time to learn about the [JavaScript console](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+console) in your browser it would have told you these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues in the line

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(pyramidColorBuffer),gl.STATIC_DRAWS);
```

`STATIC_DRAWS` is not a valid enumeration constant, the correct name is `STATIC_DRAW`. In this case you should get an *INVALID_ENUM* error.

`pyramidColorBuffer` is the buffer object (`pyramidColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer()`), but not the array for the generic vertex attributes data. The name of the array is `pyramidColors`. In this case you should get an *INVALID_OPERATION* error.

Change the line to

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(pyramidColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

to solve the issue.

Enable of the generic vertex attribute arrays is missing in your code:

```
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute );
```

But possibly this is only missing in the code  snippet which you have posted in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed what you said and now it is finally working. Thanks again!